# Why the capital S?

Tags: names, divine-names

When many write Hashem's name, they write it with the capital S. Why? And if one must capitalize a letter, why do we capitalize the S?

Comment: While I think this is a great question, I don't think it works well for this site, as it is primarily opinion-based

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I am sure that people don't simply, capitalize the S from opinion. There must be some reason

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10081/759

Comment: I personally haven't really seen that.

Comment: It's like writing "Beis HaMikdash" instead of "Beis Hamikdash". There's not much of a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hebew word being transliterated is made up of an introductory definite article (the Ha) and then the noun (shem, meaning "name"). Some people, when writing it, show the grammatical parts of the word and write the equivalent of "the Name" into the Hebrew with haShem or HaShem (The Name) to show divine majesty.

Comment: Comp. *haShem* where we are referring to something else (eg. *chillul haShem*)